# DIY Van de Graaff generator

Tags: generator, electrostatic

I have built a small Van de Graaff generator using items I found around the house, but I am unable to notice any charge accumulation on the dome. I was hoping you could help me troubleshoot the problem and find my mistake.

The bottom roller is made out of electrical tape (vinyl), the top roller from wool or cotton  and the dome from a Coca Cola can. I think the problem is from the belt, because I couldn't find rubber so I have used cotton as well.

Other than the belt I am not sure about the spacing of the brushes, so please check that too.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't know about Van de Graaff generators but it's cool that you made one from household materials! [Apparently the materials are really important though](https://stewartphysics.com/honors/honorsspring09/honorsspring09/JohnMonkus.pdf) so it probably *does* matter that the belt isn't made of rubber.

Comment: The collection comb at the top should be inside the dome. Cotton, being a natural fibre, is bound to be damp and therefore conductive to some degree, you must use a synthetic belt.

Comment: `couldn't find rubber` ... rubber bands from office supply store may work

Comment: @Neil_UK the important thing is that it should be connected to the dome and i have connected it using copper wires, about the belt i think it is causing most of the problem i have a question though if i use normal rubber band as jsotola suggested will it be good enough as it has small surface area

Comment: The aluminium can will have a plastic coating on the inside, so your wire may not actually be making electrical contact with it. You'd probably be better off wrapping something in foil rather than trying to use a can as that won't be coated.

Comment: @TomCarpenter thanks bro a great info , then if i drill the can and install the wire using a screw it should make a better contact right ? Because the screw is connected to the can and the screw is connected to the wire as well

Comment: @RYOK `the important thing is that it should be connected to the dome` - necessary, but not sufficient. Read a [the wikipedia description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_de_Graaff_generator#Description) of how a VDG works, particularly the sentence `one of which is **surrounded** by a hollow metal sphere`. Inside the can there's no electric field. This makes the top comb able to collect charge off the belt. It's also necessary to have a non-conductive belt. At VDG currents and voltages, cotton is conductive.

Comment: Thanks a lot i will add these improvements to it and share my work here for anyone who has the same problem in the future